# Pycharm в Linux не видит содержимое общей папки созданной средствами Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, pycharm, linux-mint

1. Установлен Linux Mint 19.1 в VirtualBox.
2. Установлены дополнения гостевой ОС.
3. Подключена общая папка.
4. Даны необходимые разрешения для доступа к этой папке из Linux (sudo
   adduser username vboxsf )
5. PyCharm был установлен через Software Manager.

---

Возможная подсказка. Также невозможно создать лаунчер для запуска PyCharm из консоли. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PyCharm не видит содержимое общей папки, хотя другие приложения видят. Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скачал архив с оф сайта и запустил. Всё работает. Не стоит устанавливать PyCharm через Software Manager

Comment: PyCharm из Software Manager ставится как flatpak приложение. Из Википедии: `(Flatpak) Предоставляет песочницу, в которой пользователи могут запускать приложения без влияния на основную систему. Приложения, использующие Flatpak, требуют дополнительных разрешений на использование дискового пространства.` Скорее всего проблема связана с этим.